# Turn an array format string into actual Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string which is stored like this:

```
["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]
```

Is there a direct function to convert something like this into an array? I tried `eval()` but it gave an unexpected end of file error.

Comment: what do you mean.. as in `$string = '["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]';`? if so, then just type cast it - `var_dump((array) $string);`

Comment: @treyBake yes that's how the string is stored. Thanks. I will try that. :)

Comment: You can try
`$string = '["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]';
$array = json_decode($string);
var_dump($array);` also

Comment: Try `json_decode('["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your value is like json you need just decode it like below code :

```
$string = '["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]'; 
$array = json_decode($string);
var_dump($array);
```

like **@elmasterlow** say in comment

Answer (score 1):

For that example, you could do it with `explode` and a few `str_replace` calls:

```
$string = '["something", "someone", "anything", "anyone"]';
$string = str_replace("[","",$string);
$string = str_replace("]","",$string);
$string = str_replace('"',"",$string);
$array = explode(",",$string);
var_dump($array);
```

Also `json_decode` would work, as the comments stated:

```
$array = json_decode($string,true);
```

Comment: It is, no doubt. Just wanted to show an additional way.